# Log Inverse Regression Model

Tags: regression

Let's say that we have the following regression model:

$$\ln Y=\beta_0+\beta_1\frac{1}{X}+\epsilon$$
How should I interpret the value of the estimate of $\beta_1$? I am interested into an interpretation such as "an increase of .... determines an increase of... ".

Comment: It could be relevant to now the scale of Y and X and what they measure. Could you edit yout question to provide that info? Best to put it in question instead of comments. Thx, and welcome to CV.

Comment: It is a general question. For instance, if we have the linear regression model $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 *X$, we say that: an increase by one unit of $X$, determines an average increase of $Y$ by $b_1$, where $b_1$ is the estimate of $\beta_1$.

Comment: Your model is not correctly written. Consider that if what you wrote was actually an *equality* you would need only two observations to solve for the true parameter values *exactly*. This is clearly not the case; the way you wrote your model has omitted an essential component of the actual model for the observations that you're trying to use.

Comment: I have edited to include an epsilon for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the reciprocal value of $X$ as $Z = 1/X$ then
$$\frac{\partial \log Y}{\partial Z} = \beta_1$$
which means that for each unit increase in the reciprocal value of $X$ $\log Y$ increase by $\beta_1$.

When the dependent variable is $\log$-transformed it is very common to use a percentage-interpretation such that saying:

For each unit increase in the reciprocal value of $X$ the variable $Y$ increase by $\beta_1$ percent.